# understanding cut command in python DataFrame

Tags: python

Class variable in Dataframe consist of several numbers, those numbers are :

```
5    681
6    638
7    199
4     53
8     18
3     10
```

i have seen following command on website :

```
bins = (2,6.5,8)
group_names = ['bad','good']
categories = pd.cut(df['quality'], bins, labels = group_names)
df['quality'] = categories
```

after that one  in quality column we have only two categorical variables : bad and good, i am interested how exactly it works? if number is between  2.6 and 5.8 it is bad  and all others  are  good or vice versa? please explain me this  things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'score': range(10)
})

bins = (2, 6.5, 8)
labels = ('bad', 'good')
df['quality'] = pd.cut(df['score'], bins, labels=labels)
print(df)
```

The output is:

```
   score quality
0      0     NaN
1      1     NaN
2      2     NaN
3      3     bad
4      4     bad
5      5     bad
6      6     bad
7      7    good
8      8    good
9      9     NaN
```

There are 2 bins into which score data is assigned.
`(2, 6.5]` and `(6.5, 8]`

The left end is exclusive and right end is inclusive.

All numbers in `(2, 6.5]` will be evaluated to `bad` and those in `(6.5, 8]` will be evaluated to `good`.
Those data points that are outside these intervals will not have any value and hence `NaN`.